# javascript how to filter various items in array

Tags: javascript

I need a function that filter some items from array ,like below:

how to make it? Thank you so much in advance !

```
const users = [
   {id:"1",name:"Jane"},
   {id:"2",name:"Lucy"},
   {id:"3",name:"Li Li"},
   {id:"4",name:"Hilton"},
   {id:"5",name:"Rose"},
   {id:"6",name:"Ha Ha"},
]

//user with this id need to been remove.
const filteredUsers = [
   '1','2','5'
]

function filterUsers(allUsers,filteredUsers){
   //return after filtered list
}
```

Comment: you can use `users.filter(user => filteredUsers.includes(user.id))`

Comment: Well done my friend!Thank you so much !!!